# How to connect Active Directory on on premise server from Azure AppService?

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory, azure-web-app-service

We have an existing stable web application that is hosted on an on-premise server. We have developed this application using ASP.NET.

Now are moving our project from an on-premise server to Azure AppService. In our project, we have some requirements where we connect with Active Directory to fetch user roles. This piece of code does not work when we move the application from On-premise to Azure AppService.

We have the following details to connect AD from AppService: DnsServer IP,Username and password.

I have tried this code:

```
string _path = "LDAP://<Dns Server IP>";
string domainAndUsername = "<username>";

DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(_path, domainAndUsername, "<password>");
bool found = false;

if (DirectoryEntry.Exists(_path))
{
    found = true;
}

try
{
    // Object obj = entry.NativeObject;

    DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
    search.Filter = "(SAMAccountName=" + "<username>" + ")";
    search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");

    SearchResult result = search.FindOne();
}
```

Can anyone please suggest a working code? Am I missing any configuration from Azure App Service or on-premise server?

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: Things you cannot do with Hybrid Connections
• Support LDAP, because it can require UDP.
• Support Active Directory, because you cannot domain join an App Service worker.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-hybrid-connections

Comment: @S.tenBrinke, It's throwing the error "Server couldn't be connected"

Comment: @Ashish.Wadekar I will go throw the document. Thanks

Comment: I would suggest you to please refer to the below documentation link: - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-hybrid-connections, while also refer to the below link on configuring a VM as an ADC and extending the on-premises AD to the Azure, once done, in this way, you can connect to the VM configured as an ADC through its FQDN and connect it through a managed identity: - https://azurescene.com/2020/04/17/how-to-deploy-a-domain-controller-in-microsoft-azure/